# NullPointerException when decrypting pdf with itext

Tags: pdf, itext

We are decrypting a pdf file with **itext 5.5.8**. The source code is as follows:

```
FileOutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
PDFReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(infile), password.getBytes());
PDFStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputstream);
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

At the end I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.StandardDecryption.finish(StandardDecryption.java:102)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.decryptByteArray(PdfEncryption.java:776)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getStreamBytesRaw(PdfReader.java:2634)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getStreamBytesRaw(PdfReader.java:2650)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRStream.toPdf(PRStream.java:230)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.writeTo(PdfIndirectObject.java:158)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.write(PdfWriter.java:403)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:381)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(PdfWriter.java:870)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:434)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:409)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper.close(PdfStamper.java:231)
```

The same pdf (PDF-1.4) file can be decrypted with itext version **2.1.7.5**. With this we've never had any problem.

Am I missing something? Can this problem be solved in a simple way?

Comment: iText version 2.1.7.5 does not exist as far as I know. It went from 2.1.7 straight to 5.0.0. If you have a 2.1.7.5 version, then you have an unknown fork, not distributed by iText Software.

Comment: now i tried to decrypt with itextpdf 5.0.6 and 5.5.9. In both cases i get the same NullPointer exception because cipher object is null.

Comment: I am having the same problem, any workaround so far?